# Should a view call a function?

Tags: mvc

Should a view call a helper function?

Say I pass in data from the DB to the view. The data is a unix timestamp. Should I make a call in my view to convert it to a human readable TS or should I convert it in the controller before passing it in? OR should I make a method in the model that converts...

Looking for a "best practice" or "secure coding" concerned answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a fairly trivial calculation, indeed, you could implement it in a few [lines of javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript).  It is your view that is in charge of displaying data; let it do its work.

Comment: You are right... and I guess I couldn't come up with a better example. Maybe the question should be "When should you do each"?

Comment: @Jeff: The view is responsible for massaging the data into the right form for display and that can include some calculations. Any calculations *not* related to displaying the data should go into the model.

Answer (score 0):

Since human readability depends on the target output device (big screen TV, dashboard display, watch face, voice synthesis, Morse code tones/blinks, etc.), it might be best to customize this readability in the object most closely associated with the physical output device, likely the view object.  The model objects can keep and pass on a binary encoded or computationally suitable form.